# Signal from Pi not recognized by DP monitor

Tags: display, config.txt

I'm trying to switch Raspberry Pi to a new monitor, but monitor complains about not getting HDMI signal. The old monitor was attached via HDMI-DVI cable, while new monitor has HDMI-HDMI cable and then HDMI to Display Port adapter as monitor only has old VGA and DP input. Monitor is [24" Dell E2416H](http://www.dell.com/hr/business/p/dell-e2416h-monitor/pd).

Pi boots OK and I can SSH to it.

I've tried playing with most of the parameters with the same effect, but most notably:

- `hdmi_safe=1`
- tried boosting HDMI signal with `config_hdmi_boost` to 4 and to 7
- tried booting without SD card to display test rainbow screen; no rainbow seen
- tried `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`
- tried `hdmi_drive=2`
- tried `disable_overscan=1`
- `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=1` (VGA 60Hz) and monitor native `hdmi_group=2` `hdmi_mode=82` or `hdmi_group=1` `hdmi_mode=16`.

Both result in this mode:

```
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -s
state 0x40002 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 0 modes:
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 0 modes:
```

- `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` (in combination with `hdmi_group=1` `hdmi_mode=16`) does indeed force HDMI...

...but still nothing on the screen:

```
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -s
state 0x12001a [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 1 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
pi@screenly ~ $ tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 2 modes:
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
  (prefer) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
```

Can anyone offer some advice or ideas?

**EDIT:** Solved by using HDMI to VGA adapter. However, I'd still like to know why DisplayPort doesn't work... is there anyone who successfully runs Pi on DisplayPort?

Comment: You're probably using a "passive" DisplayPort adapter. I don't think the Pi's HDMI port can power said adapter. PCs can provide more juice to it so your PC could use it. Keep it just in case.

Comment: @PandaLion98 - So "active" DisplayPort adapter could work with Pi?

Comment: It should work.